# Apply CSS change to a whole class at once with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

I want to make a change to all elements in a class using JavaScript.

Currently it looks like this:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(classToChange);

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].style.fontFamily = newFont;
}
```

My question is, is there a way to apply the new CSS property to the entire class at once (without making a new CSS style rule) or can it only be done by looping through the elements individually?

Comment: You _should_ do this via the stylesheet. (With clever use of stuff like the descendant combinator this could be as easy as setting _one_ class on a common parent element.) Otherwise, yes, of course you will have to loop through the individual items.

Comment: if you are able to use jQuery you can do $(".classtoChange").css("font-family", "newFont");

Comment: _"without making a new CSS style rule"_ Why can you not use `css`?

Comment: Your script adds the style inline to each instance, which is inefficient considering you can just add the style via CSS in one place.

Comment: @guest271314 I'm trying to make a function to be applied to an existing page, so CSS on-load wouldn't work.  I could add a <style> tag and apply it to the class that way, but I'm not sure what CSS rules may already be in place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change or add new css rules with Javascript like this

```js
var style = document.styleSheets[0].cssRules || document.styleSheets[0].rules;
for (var i = 0; i < style.length; i++) {
  if (style[i].selectorText == '.classToChange') {
    style[i].style['font-size'] = '50px';
  }
}
```

```css
.classToChange {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<p class="classToChange">Lorem</p>
```

Comment: that's a good idea.  loops through the stylesheet instead of the class elements, but it changes the existing class (if there).  Thanks!