# How can you toggle the visibility of multiple divs?

Tags: toggle

I am trying to toggle the visibility of six divs that contain vowels. I don't understand why I can't select multiple elements using the code below:

```
<div class="grid-container">
<div class="grid-item item-1 vowel">A</div>
<div class="grid-item item-2 consonant">B</div>
<div class="grid-item item-3 consonant">C</div>
<div class="grid-item item-4 consonant">D</div>
 <div class="grid-item item-5 vowel">E</div>
<div class="grid-item item-6 consonant">F</div>
<div class="grid-item item-7 consonant">G</div>
<div class="grid-item item-8 consonant">H</div>
 <div class="grid-item item-9 vowel">I</div>
<div class="grid-item item-10 consonant">J</div>
<div class="grid-item item-11 consonant">K</div>
<div class="grid-item item-12 consonant">L</div>
<div class="grid-item item-13 consonant">M</div>
<div class="grid-item item-14 consonant">N</div>
<div class="grid-item item-15 vowel">O</div>
<div class="grid-item item-16 consonant">P</div>
 <div class="grid-item item-17 consonant">Q</div>
<div class="grid-item item-18 consonant">R</div>
<div class="grid-item item-19 consonant">S</div>
<div class="grid-item item-20 consonant">T</div>
 <div class="grid-item item-21 vowel">U</div>
<div class="grid-item item-22 consonant">V</div>
<div class="grid-item item-23 consonant">W</div>
<div class="grid-item item-24 consonant">X</div>
<div class="grid-item item-25 vowel">Y</div>
<div class="grid-item item-26 consonant">Z</div>
```

`

```
    //toggle vowels
    
    const toggleVowelsButton = document.getElementById('button9');
    toggleVowelsButton.addEventListener('click', hideVowels);
    
    function hideVowels() {
     let vowels = document.getElementsByClassName('vowel');
     if (vowels.style.visibility === "hidden") {
      vowels.style.visibility = "visible";
      }else {
        vowels.style.visibility ="hidden";
      }
    }
```

Any advice on how to select and manipulate multiple elements would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37726229/apply-css-change-to-a-whole-class-at-once-with-javascript) might prove helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName()` returns an `HTMLCollection`, which you have to iterate through. Here is a working solution (also see [pen](https://codepen.io/AntonC9018/pen/GRWqYNJ)):

```js
function hideVowels() {
  let vowels = document.getElementsByClassName("vowel");
  for (let i = 0; i < vowels.length; i = i + 1) {
    let vowel = vowels[i];
    if (vowel.style.visibility === "hidden") {
      vowel.style.visibility = "visible";
    } else {
      vowel.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
  }
}

hideVowels();
```

I would also recommend looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37726229/apply-css-change-to-a-whole-class-at-once-with-javascript).

When you get more comfortable with web basics, I highly recommend using a frontend framework for stuff like this. My favorite is [VueJS](https://vuejs.org/).

Comment: Thank you for the help.  Your solution works great.  I'll take a look at the question you recommended and VueJs.